# Improving preformance by using multiple threads/cores

Tags: python, performance, python-multithreading

I have a game (using pygame) that I want to improve the performance of. I noticed that when I have low fps the game was only using 20% of the CPU at most, is there a way I can use threads to utilize more of the CPU?

I have tried to implement threads already, but seem to have no good luck, some help would be appreciated.

This function is what is causing the lag:

## First Version

```
def SearchFood(self):
    if not self.moving:
        tempArr = np.array([])

        for e in entityArr:
            if type(e) == Food:
                if e.rect != None and self.viewingRect != None:
                    if self.viewingRect.colliderect(e.rect):
                        tempArr = np.append(tempArr, e)

        if tempArr.size > 0:
            self.nearestFood = sorted(tempArr, key=lambda e: Mag((self.x - e.x, self.y - e.y)))[0]
```

## Second Version (Slower)

```
def SearchFood(self):
    if not self.moving:
        s_arr = sorted(entityArr, key=lambda e: math.hypot(self.x - e.x, self.y - e.y))

        for e, i in enumerate(s_arr):
            if type(e) != Food:
                self.nearestFood = None

            else:
                self.nearestFood = s_arr[i]
                break
```

I look through the entire list of entities and sort it after if the entity is food and the distance to the thing that wants to eat said food. Problem is that the entity array is 500 elements (and more) long and thus takes a really long time to iterate through and sort. Then to remedy that I want to make use of more of the CPU with the use of threading.

Here's the full script if that helps: https://github.com/Lobsternator/Game-Of-Life-Esque.git

Comment: You'll only be able to expand processing power in this if you have all the available  objects for [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager) ready and queued up, so if you generate one at a time or need it for ordering it will be more difficult. Also keep in mind Python is really bad at this parallel thing and this "official" hack needs to be implemented carefully as shown (specially for Windows) or it will hang either the application or your whole machine. Might wanna try optimizing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multithreading in Python is nearly useless (for CPU-intensive tasks like this), and multiprocessing, while viable, requires expensive marshaling of data between processes or careful design. I don't believe either one is applicable to your case.

However, unless you have a huge amount of objects in your game, you shouldn't need to use multiple cores for your scenario. The issue seems more one of algorithmic complexity.

You can improve the performance of your code in several ways:

- Keep an index of entities by type (e.g. a dict from entity-type to set of entities, which you update as entities are created/removed), which would allow you to easily find all the "food" entities without scanning through all entities in the game.
- Find the nearest food entity using a simple "min" operation (which is `O(n)`) instead of sorting all the foods by distance (which is `O(n*logn)`).

  - If this is still slow you can apply a culling technique, where you first filter foods to those within an easily-computed range (e.g. a rectangle around the player), then find the nearest one by applying the more expensive distance computation only to those.
- Make loops tighter by avoiding checking unnecessary conditions inside them, and whenever possible using builtin selection/creation constructs rather than iterating through large lists of objects.

e.g. you can end up with something like:

```py
def find_nearest_food(self):
  food_entities = self._entities_by_type[Food]
  nearest_food = min(food_entities, key=lambda entity: distance_sq(self, entity))
  return nearest_food

def distance_sq(ent1, ent2):
  # we don't need an expensive square root operation if we're just comparing distances
  dx, dy = (ent1.x - ent2.x), (ent1.y - ent2.y)
  return dx * dx + dy * dy
```

You can optimize further by keeping entity positions as NumPy vectors instead of separate `x` and `y` properties, which would allow you to use NumPy operations to calculate distance, e.g. `distance_sq = (ent1.pos - ent2.pos)**2` or just `np.linalg.norm` for regular distance computation. This might also be useful for other vector arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, threading does not increase the number of used core. You must use multiprocessing instead.
The doc : https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager